# Print Final Statement Outside For Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to print a final statement that says "The 50th bus arrives at HH:MM." But it appears my print statement is still in my for loop. How do I get it out of it? Also, it seems like my output is still in brackets. I'm not sure how to get rid of that. Sorry, I'm very new to programming.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import random

l=[]
for i in range (50):
    def nextTime(rateParameter):
        return -math.log(1.0 - random.random()) / rateParameter
    a = np.round(nextTime(1/15),0)
    l.append(a)
cum_l = np.cumsum(l)
print(cum_l)

print("The 50th bus arrives at ", cum_l//60,":", cum_l%60,2)
```

Comment: As posted, neither of the print statements are inside a loop.  Perhaps the indentation in your post does not match the actual indentation in your program?

Comment: Also, there's no need to define the `nextTime` function 50 times.

Comment: Your program does not even run for me. I'm encountering a `ZeroDivisionError`. I think it has something to do with the `1 / 15` part.

Comment: @DrewDavis This is Python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Print` is not in `for` loop. The reason you think that your `print` is in `for` loop is because you print `cum_l` which is a `list`. But you need only last element:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import random

rateParameter = 1/15

def nextTime(rateParameter):
        return -math.log(1.0 - random.random()) / rateParameter

l=[]
for i in range (50):
    a = np.round(nextTime(rateParameter), 0)
    l.append(a)

cum_l = np.cumsum(l)
#print(cum_l)

output = ""
last = len(cum_l) - 1

output += str(cum_l[-1]//60) + ":" + str(cum_l[-1]%60)

print("The 50th bus arrives at: ", output)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still getting the final statement about the 50th bus in a for loop. I just need it to print the time of the final bus.

Comment: I updated my answer to print only last element of list of bus arrival times.